# How to extract part of an attribute value from xml in C#

Tags: xml, xslt, c#-4.0

I just need to extract the part between ':' and '/' in the attribute "PointName".
Following is the sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Trend xmlns="Data">   
<tblPoint PointName="ABC:XYZ123/AAA.DDD-111.MMM.MV-3.PV" UOM="0">
        <tblValue UTCDateTime="2017-07-18T05:07:47" val="3" />
        <tblValue UTCDateTime="2017-07-18T05:08:27" val="0" />   
</tblPoint>   
<tblPoint PointName="BCD:XYZ234/AAA.DDD-222.MMM.MV-3.PV" UOM="0">
        <tblValue UTCDateTime="2017-07-18T06:01:12" val="0" />
        <tblValue UTCDateTime="2017-07-18T06:01:13" val="0" />   
</tblPoint> 
</Trend>
```

I'm currently using the following code:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath); // xmlFilePath - where the above XML file is located.
var ns = XNamespace.Get("Data");
var pointNames = xdoc.Root.Elements(ns + "tblPoint").Attributes("PointName").ToList();
```

I wish there was a way to populate the pointNames like this:

```
var pointNames = xdoc.Root.Elements(ns + "tblPoint").Attributes("PointName").StringBetween(':', '/').ToList();
```

I would hate to use a loop on pointNames because tblPoint nodes can be thousands in number in the XML.

Comment: Why is this tagged XSLT?

Comment: I believe this problem can better be solved by using XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a slight modification of [michael.hor257k's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3016153/michael-hor257k) stylesheet (I'm using a '.' character as a delimiter since I couldn't get newlines to work):

```
//A static field defined in some class
static readonly xsl = @"

<xsl:stylesheet version=""1.0"" 
xmlns:xsl=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform""
xmlns:d=""Data"">
<xsl:output method=""text""/>

<xsl:template match=""/d:Trend"">
    <xsl:for-each select=""d:tblPoint"">
        <xsl:value-of select=""substring-before(substring-after(@PointName, ':'), '/')"" />
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping=""yes"">.</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>".Trim();
```

Then, in some method:

```
var xsldoc = XDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xsl)));
var xslt = new System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform();
var ms = new MemoryStream();

xslt.Load(xsldoc.CreateReader());    
xslt.Transform(xdoc.CreateReader(), null, ms); //xdoc is your XML document that you loaded.
ms.Position = 0;

var sr = new StreamReader(ms);

var xs = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(new[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (var x in xs)
   Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Output is:

```
XYZ123
XYZ234
```

If we can get newlines to work, then it will be much more efficient since we won't need to read in the entire string representing the transform.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather trivial to do in XSLT - try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:d="Data">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/d:Trend">
    <xsl:for-each select="d:tblPoint">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(@PointName, ':'), '/')" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
XYZ123
XYZ234
```

Comment: Great! do you know how to use the XSLT solution in C#; or are you just an XSLT guru? :)

Comment: I am afraid I know nothing about C#  (though I would think that's something you could find out in a matter of minutes).